# How to remove blank page after title page in LaTex?

Tags: latex

I'm trying to use latex to create a document but a random page is created after the front page and I'm not sure of the best way to remove it. As you can see in the document class I've added openany which should make the document one-sided and yet this page is still being randomly added. I've added the code below and an image of whats produced. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, openany]{book}
\RequirePackage{fullpage}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{ragged2e}
\RequirePackage{mathptmx}
\RequirePackage{anyfontsize}
\RequirePackage{t1enc}
\RequirePackage{setspace}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\graphicspath{ {figures/} }
\RequirePackage{array}



\RequirePackage{etoolbox} % for "\patchcmd" macro
\makeatletter
% No extra space between chapter number and chapter header lines:
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead} {\vskip 20}{\vskip 0} {}{}
% Reduce extra space between chapter header and section header lines by 50%:
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead} {\vskip 40}{\vskip 20}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vskip 40}{\vskip 20}{}{} % for unnumbered chapters
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \begin{center}
            \vspace*{1cm}
            
            \Huge
            \textbf{Engineering + Engineering = Engineering}
            
            \vspace{0.5cm}
            \LARGE
            Design of of something something something
            \includegraphics[width=0.7\columnwidth]{university.jpg}
            \centering
            
            
            
            
            \textbf{John Smith}
            
            \vfill
            
            A thesis submitted to the School of Engineering\\ 
            at the University of Hull for the degree of\\ 
            MASTER OF ENGINEERING    
            
            
            \vspace{0.8cm}
            
            
            
            
            
            
            
            \Large
            School of  Engineering\\
            University of Hull\\
            United Kingdom\\
            October 2023
            
        \end{center}
    \end{titlepage}
    
    \newpage
    \frontmatter
    \pagenumbering{Roman}
    \centering
    
    \topskip0pt
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \Huge
    
    \normalsize
    \par
    \emph{“Some Sort of Inspirational Quote.” }
    John Smith
    \vspace*{\fill}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cross-network duplicate: [How to remove blank page after title page in LaTex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/574049/5764)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been answered on a more suitable network ([How to remove blank page after title page in LaTex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/574049/5764)).

Answer (score 4):

Quick hack:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, openany]{book}
\RequirePackage{fullpage}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{ragged2e}
\RequirePackage{mathptmx}
\RequirePackage{anyfontsize}
\RequirePackage{t1enc}
\RequirePackage{setspace}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\graphicspath{ {figures/} }
\RequirePackage{array}



\RequirePackage{etoolbox} % for "\patchcmd" macro
\makeatletter
% No extra space between chapter number and chapter header lines:
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead} {\vskip 20}{\vskip 0} {}{}
% Reduce extra space between chapter header and section header lines by 50%:
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead} {\vskip 40}{\vskip 20}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vskip 40}{\vskip 20}{}{} % for unnumbered chapters
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \begin{center}
            \vspace*{1cm}
            
            \Huge
            \textbf{Engineering + Engineering = Engineering}
            
            \vspace{0.5cm}
            \LARGE
            Design of of something something something
            \includegraphics[width=0.7\columnwidth]{example-image-duck}
            \centering
            
            
            
            
            \textbf{John Smith}
            
            \vfill
            
            A thesis submitted to the School of Engineering\\ 
            at the University of Hull for the degree of\\ 
            MASTER OF ENGINEERING    
            
            
            \vspace{0.8cm}
            
            
            
            
            
            
            
            \Large
            School of  Engineering\\
            University of Hull\\
            United Kingdom\\
            October 2023
            
        \end{center}
    \end{titlepage}
    
    {\let\cleardoublepage\relax \frontmatter}
    \pagenumbering{Roman}
    \centering
    
    \topskip0pt
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \Huge
    \normalsize
    \par
    \emph{“Some Sort of Inspirational Quote.” }
    John Smith
    \vspace*{\fill}


\end{document}
```